# Why do we turn $|\tan^{-1}\theta|$ to $-\tan^{-1}θ$?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-trigonometric-functions

In this question, why did we turn $|\tan^{-1}\theta|$ to $-\tan^{-1}θ$ in the highlighted step?

[image]

Why is there a negative sign? I first thought that the negative sign was because $\frac\pi2 < \theta < \pi$, so $\tan\theta$ is negative on this domain. But if $\tan\theta$ is negative, why do we put a (-) sign and make it positive?

in a similar question [below], we allowed it to be +ve and that seems correct, but i don't understand why in the first question we need to add (-) sign?

[image]

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of the bars $| \cdots |$ in the expression $|\tan^{-1} \theta|$?

Comment: i think Modulus function?

Comment: Nope. It's the absolute value function.

Comment: yeh, still why did we put (-) after it?

Comment: Because in the previous line it is specified that $\theta$ lies between $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\pi$. In that range, the tangent is negative.

Comment: are we putting the (-) sign to convert the range from -ve to +ve so it matches the absolute value function?

Comment: That is correct. In fact, the *very definition* of the absolute value function says "$|x|=-x$ if $x$ is negative" (and $|x|=x$ if $x$ is positive).

Comment: $|\tan \theta|$ is positive, so you are changing it by $-\tan \theta$ which is also positive.

Answer (score 1):

In the second line of the equation above, $\sec \theta \lt -1$ is valid in two  quadrants: the second and third quadrants.

Substituting $x = \sec \theta$ in the denominator, $\sqrt {\sec^2 \theta - 1} = \sqrt {\tan^2 \theta} = |\tan \theta| = \pm \tan \theta$, but since you're in the range of $\frac {\pi}{2} \lt \theta \lt \pi$, you'll be in the second quadrant; as $\tan \theta$ is negative in the second quadrant, we choose the negative sign, because the absolute value function defines $|x| = -x$, when x is negative.